# How can I create unique property apart from primary key in ontology

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Is there any way to create a unique property apart from the primary key in ontology object or Is there any way to check for duplication of data in particular field throught workshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a property to any value when you're creating an object. Property values come from two places:

1. Backing dataset pipeline - You can change the logic creating the backing dataset to create values that would be unique. Easiest way is to use a window and apply the `row_number` function. You can find an example [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-window-functions/#ranking-functions)
2. Object creation action -

- (1) You can have your object creation action to be [function backed](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/function-actions-overview/index.html). Then inside the function you can create any sort of unique values you want. There is even an [example in the documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/functions/edits-generate-id/index.html) on how to set up rids.
- (2) Alternatively you can have a function in your workshop module that creates a new unique value and sends it through to the creation action as a parameter. This way you can show it to the user, allow them to modify it and disable the action if the value is not unique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used function backed action. I had one more question, Can we add a validation check in the action forms that checks if the entered value for one field already exists in the one of the object of object set?

Comment: Not in the validation section but if you're using a function you can check that value in there and throw a user facing error if they try to enter duplicate values.